# How can I check what e-mail address is tied to my OpenID?

Tags: openid

I'm using Yahoo as an OpenID provider, but they give me pretty much zero control over it. I would like to know what e-mail address is tied to said OpenID.
(I have a non-Yahoo e-mail account selected as primary, but I'm suspecting Yahoo is not respecting that setting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo's OpenID settings are derived off of your Yahoo profile information. When a Relying Party (An RP is a site, like StackExchange sites, asking for your OpenID) asks for information like an e-mail address, or a real name, etc., Yahoo should be providing it with your primary address you've specified in the profile management pages.

The best way I know to test it is to sign into a site you've never signed in before. Due to the nature of OpenID, you're pretty safe in doing this, the problem is that the RP has to ask via Attribute Exchange (AX) for your e-mail address.

I just tested my Yahoo OpenID login on jyte.com, and I got a popup window preview page (at Yahoo) you have to click 'agree' on, and that told me what e-mail address it was going to pass on to Jyte.

So, my suggestion is to head to [Jyte](http://jyte.com), click Sign In, click the Yahoo! button and enter your Yahoo! account username. After signing in, if necessary, you should see the e-mail address Yahoo is going to pass onto Jyte.

You don't have to click "Agree", feel free to just close the window and move on if you have no interest in Jyte. This was just a suggestion in order to confirm your suspicion regarding the chosen profile e-mail address.

[edit]
And, lastly, if you don't like Yahoo's level of control, pick a new provider.
I suggest buying a domain for yourself, and using it to delegate to OpenID providers. In my 6(?)'ish years of using OpenID, I've been through LiveJournal (first place to have it), Wordpress.com (thinking I was going to be there forever, ha!), and I've settled on MyOpenID.

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: I'm actually already using my own domain as a delegate, but I'm delegating it to Yahoo, so the issues remain. But thanks!